# Keep nested field code in LINK field

Tags: microsoft-word

In my word document, I have defined a bookmark with `{ SET Model "c:\\test.xlsb" }`.

Later, I embed a link to this Excel workbook with

```
{LINK Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12 {REF Model} Sheet1!R1C1:R5C4 \a \f 0 \p}
```

which works as expected in the first run, ie it shows the linked document when updating the fields.

However, once the field is updated, the nested `REF` field is converted back to plain text, ie. my above formula looks like this:

```
{LINK Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12 "c:\\test.xlsb" Sheet1!R1C1:R5C4 \a \f 0 \p}
```

Is there any way to keep the nested `REF` or centrally updated the location of the linked Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Word will always "resolve"/unlink nested fields within `LINK` fields, usually sooner rather than later.

If you are the only user of this document, you could consider something like the following. Suppose you want to have multiple `LINK`s to the same workbook. Then

Insert all the `LINK` fields and get the document to work for one Workbook.

Change "`LINK`" in all the relevant `LINK` fields to another string, preferably something that will not appear elsewhere such as "`ABCLINK`".

Optionally, insert a `{ SET ABCLINK "Some text to remind you how to use this document" }` field.

Update (re-execute) all the `ABCLINK` fields.

Insert the nested `{ REF Model }` fields and any other `REF` fields where you need them.

Save that document.

To use the document, you use it more like a template (you could make it into a Word template if you wanted), e.g.

- open it
- save a copy
- modify the value of the Model bookmark and any others
- update all the fields
- use find/replace to replace `AAALINK` by `LINK`
- update all the fields

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know a way how to centrally update Excel links then (except search & replace) or VBA?

Comment: @Peter Albert: no, sorry, I would tend to use VBA for that, unless by "centrally" you mean in a single dialog box, i.e. the Edit Link dialog box - but even using that, you're going to have to edit every single link that points to the Excel workbook.